# Merge duplicate values in json using ruby

Tags: ruby, json, merge, duplicates

I have the following **item.json** file

```
{
    "items": [
      {
        "brand": "LEGO",
        "stock": 55,
        "full-price": "22.99",
      },
      {
        "brand": "Nano Blocks",
        "stock": 12,
        "full-price": "49.99",
      },
      {
        "brand": "LEGO",
        "stock": 5,
        "full-price": "199.99",
      }
    ]
}
```

There are two items named LEGO and I want to get output for the total number of stock for the individual brand.

In ruby file **item.rb** i have code like:

```
require 'json'

path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../data/products.json')
file = File.read(path)
products_hash = JSON.parse(file)

products_hash["items"].each do |brand|
puts "Stock no: #{brand["stock"]}"
end
```

I got output for stock no individually for each brand wherein I need the stock to be summed for two brand name "LEGO" displayed as one.
Anyone has solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json = File.open(path,'r:utf-8',&:read) # in case the JSON uses UTF-8
items = JSON.parse(json)['items']
stock_by_brand = items
  .group_by{ |h| h['brand'] }
  .map do |brand,array|
    [ brand,
      array
        .map{ |item| item['stock'] }
        .inject(:+) ]
  end
  .to_h
#=> {"LEGO"=>60, "Nano Blocks"=>12}
```

It works like this:

- [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) takes the array of items and creates a hash mapping the brand name to an array of all `item` hashes with that brand
- [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) turns each brand/array pair in that hash into an array of the brand (unchanged) followed by:

  - [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) on the array of items picks out just the `"stock"` counts, and then
  - [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) sums them all together
- [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-to_h) then turns that array of two-value arrays into a hash, mapping the brand to the sum of `stock` values.

If you want simpler code that's less *[functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)* and possibly easier to understand:

```
stock_by_brand = {}  # an empty hash
items.each do |item|
  stock_by_brand[ item['brand'] ] ||= 0 # initialize to zero if unset
  stock_by_brand[ item['brand'] ] += item['stock']
end
p stock_by_brand     #=> {"LEGO"=>60, "Nano Blocks"=>12}
```

Answer (score 1):

To see what your JSON string looks like, let's create it from your hash, which I've denoted `h`:

```
require 'json'

j = JSON.generate(h)
  #=> "{\"items\":[{\"brand\":\"LEGO\",\"stock\":55,\"full-price\":\"22.99\"},{\"brand\":\"Nano Blocks\",\"stock\":12,\"full-price\":\"49.99\"},{\"brand\":\"LEGO\",\"stock\":5,\"full-price\":\"199.99\"}]}"
```

After reading that from a file, into the variable `j`, we can now parse it to obtain the value of `"items"`:

```
arr = JSON.parse(j)["items"]
  #=> [{"brand"=>"LEGO", "stock"=>55, "full-price"=>"22.99"},
  #    {"brand"=>"Nano Blocks", "stock"=>12, "full-price"=>"49.99"},
  #    {"brand"=>"LEGO", "stock"=>5, "full-price"=>"199.99"}]
```

One way to obtain the desired tallies is to use a counting hash:

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|g,h| h.update(g["brand"]=>h[g["brand"]]+g["stock"])}
  #=> {"LEGO"=>60, "Nano Blocks"=>12}
```

`Hash.new(0)` creates an empty hash (represented by the block variable `h`) with  with a default value of zero<sup>1</sup>. That means that `h[k]` returns zero if the hash does not have a key `k`.

For the first element of `arr` (represented by the block variable `g`) we have:

```
g["brand"] #=> "LEGO"
g["stock"] #=> 55
```

Within the block, therefore, the calculation is:

```
g["brand"] => h[g["brand"]]+g["stock"]
  #=> "LEGO" => h["LEGO"] + 55
```

Initially `h` has no keys, so `h["LEGO"]` returns the default value of zero, resulting in `{ "LEGO"=>55 }` being merged into the hash `h`. As `h` now has a key `"LEGO"`, `h["LEGO"]`, will not return the default value in subsequent calculations.

Another approach is to use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) {|g,h| h.update(g["brand"]=>g["stock"]) {|_,o,n| o+n}}
  #=> {"LEGO"=>60, "Nano Blocks"=>12}
```

<sup>1 `k=>v` is shorthand for `{ k=>v }` when it appears as a method's argument.</sup>